# Problems uploading a file via WebDAV?

Tags: curl, ssl, webdav

I've configured on my Linux server (SLES11) with IHS Webserver with [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) enabled. A file upload via `curl` is successful using a URL like this:

```
$ curl --insecure --upload-file testfile.txt \
    https://<URL>.com/upload/hro/ -u hro:$HRO_WEBDAV_PASSWORD
```

Resulting in this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>201 Created</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Created</h1>
<p>Resource /upload/hro/testfile.txt has been created.</p>
<hr />
<address>IBM_HTTP_Server Server at <URL> Port 443</address>
```

If I try this with "localhost" instead of the URL it doesn't worked. I get a SSL Error:

```
$ curl --insecure --upload-file testfile.txt \
    https://localhost/upload/hro/ -u hro:$HRO_WEBDAV_PASSWORD
```

Resulting in this:

```
curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

This is coherent because the certificate is signed for the url not for "localhost". But I have used the option `--insecure` and I've intended for this through the use of this option to ignore this failure.

#### Questions

- What should I do to use `localhost` for `curl`?
- Is there no option for this script to use the localhost URL?

Comment: Is your webserver listening on all interfaces? `netstat -anp |grep 443` to confirm.

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at this SO Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192837/ssl-peer-certificate-or-ssh-remote-key-was-not-ok

Comment: yes, my webserver is listening on all interfaces

 $ netstat -anp |grep 443
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -

Comment: Can you run your `curl` command with the `-v` for verbose switch?